# Alarms, whose trigger times are longer apart don't execute

Tags: android, android-notifications, alarmmanager, background-service, foreground-service

My goal is to have the program set alarms and once each of the alarms is triggered, a specific audio is played.

The problem is that this works if the trigger time differences created by `set_alarm` are small, for instance if the first and the last trigger are less than 10 minutes apart.

But if the trigger time distance is greater than that, the triggers won't be activated after some time, ie no sound is played.

What do I need to change?

What I tried:

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myPackage">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <application
        ...
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <service android:name=".BService" android:stopWithTask="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AudPlayer" android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="my.tag"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
package myPackage;

import ...


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AudPlayer ap;

    Intent i_neu;
    boolean running = false;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        intent = new Intent(this, AudPlayer.class);
        ap = new AudPlayer();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("my.tag");
        intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        registerReceiver(ap, intentFilter);
        

        final ImageButton btnGO = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnGO);
        btnGO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!running) {
                    running = true;
                    view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
                    i_neu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BService.class);
                    Bundle ints = new Bundle();
                    ints.putInt(...);
                    i_neu.putExtras(ints);
                    startService(i_neu);
                } else {
                    stopService(i_neu);
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

BService

```
package package;


import ...

public class BService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void notificationDialog() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        ...
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                ...
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                ...
        Notification not = notificationBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(1, not);
        startForeground(1,not);
    }

    AudPlayer ap;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final int whatever = intent.getIntExtra("whatever",0);
        ...
        ap = new AudPlayer();
        ap.init(this);
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.setTimeInMillis(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        ap.set_alarm(this,time.getTimeInMillis(),R.raw.beginn);
        time.setTimeInMillis(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+whatever);
        ....
        ap.set_alarm(this,time.getTimeInMillis(),R.raw.beginn);
        time.setTimeInMillis(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+whatever2);
        ap.set_alarm(this,time.getTimeInMillis(),R.raw.beginn);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

AudPlayer

```
package myPackage;

import ...

public class AudPlayer extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "T");
        wl.acquire();
        final int ResID = intent.getIntExtra("ResID",0);
        final long When = intent.getLongExtra("When",0);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, ResID);
        AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        while (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        wl.release();
    }
    
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    Intent intent;
    Bundle Resids;

    public void init(Context context)
    {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent = new Intent(context, AudPlayer.class);
        Resids = new Bundle();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context, long When, int ResID)
    {
        Resids.putInt("ResID",ResID);
        Resids.putLong("When",When);
        intent.putExtras(Resids);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int)When, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, When, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are confusing `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which is the current unix time in milliseconds and `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` which is milliseconds since the last device reboot. Calling `time.setTimeInMillis(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())` will give you some random point in time since the method expects a unix timestamp

Comment: So you suggest replacing SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() with System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Yes since that is the only format `Calendar` understands. This also means you need to use `alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, ...)` since `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` again returns a unix timestamp

Comment: I did, same behaviour.